# Спарсить sxml в html [ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, xml

Ubuntu
Есть страница вида: 192.168.1.2/ups.sxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/lib/ups/griser240.xsl"?>
<generex>
<nms>
<report time="19.04.2017 15:58:01" refresh="10" flags="0">
<status>
<values>
<value name="_oemViewName" val="GRISER240"/>
<value name="_platform" val="cs121"/>
<value name="_selected_ups_id" val="0"/>
<value name="AUX1CFG" val="-1"/>
<value name="AUX2CFG" val="-1"/>
<value name="AUX3CFG" val="-1"/>
<value name="AUX4CFG" val="-1"/>
<value name="AUX1STATE" val="0"/>
<value name="AUX2STATE" val="0"/>
<value name="AUX3STATE" val="0"/>
<value name="AUX4STATE" val="0"/>
<value name="AUX1TEXT" val="AUX Port 1"/>
<value name="AUX2TEXT" val="AUX Port 2"/>
<value name="AUX3TEXT" val="AUX Port 3"/>
<value name="AUX4TEXT" val="AUX Port 4"/>
<value name="SYS_NAME" val="AEG Protect 3M"/>
<value name="SYS_CONTACT" val="Aleksey Izheev"/>
<value name="TEMP1OFFSET" val="0.00"/>
<value name="TEMP1SCALE" val="2.55"/>
<value name="TEMP1" val="0.00"/>
<value name="TEMP1LOCATION" val="Temp. Sensor 1"/>
<value name="TEMP1UNIT" val="Degree Celsius"/>
<value name="TEMP1LO_THRES" val="0.00"/>
<value name="TEMP1HI_THRES" val="100.00"/>
<value name="TEMP1TYPE" val="Custom"/>
.....
```

Браузер показывает формат html

[image: Страница]

Как мне спарсить именно html?

Comment: можно воспользоваться каким-нибудь xml-процессором. xsltproc, xmlto (такие пакеты должны быть в репозитории дистрибутива) и т.п.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подошел xsltproc. Спасибо @alexanderbarakin [@alexander barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin)

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s http://192.168.1.2/ups.sxml > /scripts/pars_ups/pars.sxml

xsltproc /scripts/pars_ups/pars.sxml  --html --output /scripts/pars_ups/parsed.html
```

Comment: @alexanderbarakin исправил, спасибо